# Trac not showing git repo

Tags: git, terminal, server, trac

I added a git repo to my trac server but it won't come up in the Source Browser/Git Browser. I have other git repos that show up just fine. Any reason why I can add a git repo to my server but it won't show up on git?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which Trac version you are running. If I had to guess, you either need to upgrade to a recent Trac 1.0.x version (1.0.13 is the latest), or append `.git` to your path. If that doesn't fix the issue, [check the logs](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTroubleshooting#ChecktheLogs).